# NotificationManager and tags

Tags: android, tags, notificationmanager

I'm trying to figure out what the tag parameter on some of the NotificationManager's methods actually does as the Google documentation sucks a bit here.

Am I right in thinking that I can set a NOTIFICATION_ID for a certain type of notification, for example a SMS message then having a tag unique.

This means when I launch the app, I could just clear all notifications with that ID?

I'm sorry if this is really basic, but Google should explain this better :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the NOTIFICATION_ID seems to be an identifier for the "type" of notification, for example one for SMS messages and the tag could be something like "Messages From Bob".

I'm not 100% sure on this, however it seems to work like this

Joe